# The Smallest non zero binomial coefficient of n over a modulo prime p .

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

Let $p$ be a prime, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and let $m$ be the largest integer such that $p^m$ divides $n$. Then , the smallest $j\geq1$ such that $\binom{n}{j}$ is non zero modulo $p$, is $j=p^m$.
No idea how to prove this one

Comment: You could start looking into the usual formula for binomial coefficients and count how many factors of $p$ appears in the numerator and the denominator. Seems to me like the immediate first idea anyone should try.

Comment: Can you prove it for the case $m=1?$ Or $m=0?$